# Is it necessary to use 4-pole circuit breaker for TN-C-S system?

Tags: protection, standard, grounding, circuit-breaker

It seems that in TN-C-S system is necessary to use 4-pole circuit breaker, I want to know it's correct or not? and if it's correct, which document or standard is used to prove it?

Comment: You need to look at the wiring standards of the particular country in which you want to install the breaker.

Answer (score 1):

TN-C-S system, neutral line is earthed at source side, assuming three phase supply (three lines and using neutral line from source), to isolate the complete source you need a 4 pole circuit breaker

Comment: thanks. Also I need a document to prove it. do you have any document?

Comment: no valid document, just from the idea of using circuit breaker, the purpose is to isolate the input from source if load is more that expected